# Background image not displaying on old IE versions

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I m really having a hard time displaying a background image on old IE versions (6-8).

Here is my code:

```
#top
{
background-image: url(http://some-domain.com/myimage.jpg) no-repeat;
background-color:#830703;
border-bottom: 1px solid #303130;
height: 128px;
width:100%;
overflow: hidden;
zoom:1;
}
```

I have tried it to write it in many different ways but it didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `background-image: url(http://some-domain.com/myimage.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;` either that or just `background: url(http://some-domain.com/myimage.jpg) no-repeat;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should actually never show up correctly as you have a small syntactical error. you mixed background-image and background-repeat. Either use the background-shortcut or just split them up:

```
background-image: url(http://some-domain.com/myimage.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle then? because this is pretty much a standard code that should work everywhere (and yeah, even in IE6 :-) )

Comment: sorry, I m not familiar with jsfiddle

Comment: then plz take a look at it. you will need it in stackoverflow :) Create a fiddle that reproduces your problem in the browsers you mentioned and we can find your problem and post an answer directly with a new fiddle

Comment: well for me it doesnt. Maybe I should disable CSS caching in this CMS.

Comment: well, your code is now actually correct, so no problem here. As you mentioned in the other answer, your test-environment is netrenderer. maybe this one makes the problem. Do you have a real IE somewhere (even newer ones). If you press F12 they have developer tools like firebug. You can emulate old browser versions there. If your image shows up with this method then everything is just fine, trust me. If not... well that would be pretty interesting

Answer (score 1):

Use the below.

```
#top
{
    background: url(http://some-domain.com/myimage.jpg) no-repeat #830703;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #303130;
    height: 128px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom:1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have worked it a couple of times and it works perfectly fine. Show your live code. - @user3069436

Comment: If I try this, my image disappears completly (on firefox aswell as on IE 7 & 8) - I am using netrenderer.

Comment: The site uses creates cached css files - so I have to edited the "standard css" file and the cached one. Maybe this there is an issue ?

Comment: maybe it's a problem of netrenderer and you shouldn't really care ;)

Comment: that's because you still use background-image and not the background shortcut for shortcut syntax :)

Comment: ah OK I see. Well the firefox part is fixed now - I ll try to find a real IE now in order to see whether the problem really exists or if netrenderer is fooling me.

Comment: Thats exactly what I have mentioned above. Dont use `background-image` attribute. Just use `background` with your image as well as background color inside it and that will work on IE - @user3069436

Comment: OK thank you guys. I tested it on IE 6 and it worked, so I suppose it will work on 7-8 aswell.

Comment: so just upvote all of the provided answers pls to credit everyone and just accept a random one you like most. They are actually all correct (accept the one with the color that overrides your image, the solution is right but the reason is just totally wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Use either one of the below

```
background-image: url(http://some-domain.com/myimage.jpg) no-repeat;
background-color:#830703;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

or

```
background: url(http://some-domain.com/myimage.jpg) no-repeat #830703;
```

Comment: [Agreed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395846/background-image-not-displaying-on-old-ie-versions/20395879#20395879)

Comment: usually some additional text to explain the solution is nice but as the solution itself is correct I upvoted in name of the asker :)

Answer (score 1):

**please do follow**

```
background:#830703 url('http://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/v1_53a1fa6a.png') no-repeat;
```

Comment: usually some additional text to explain the solution is nice but as the solution itself is correct I upvoted in name of the asker :)